# Add and remove class in for each loop on scroll

Tags: javascript

I want to add and remove a class on couple of elements depending on scroll position. The problem is that it only works on the first element in the array. Second element gets totally ignored. What am i doing wrong?

My code:

HTML:

```
<header data-header>
  my header
</header>
<header data-header>
  my second header
</header>
```

JS

```
export default class Navigation {
  constructor() {

    this.headers = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-header]')];
    this.lastscrolltop;

    this.headers.forEach((el) => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if(scrollTop > this.lastscrolltop) {
          el.classList.add('myclass');
        } else{
          el.classList.remove('myclass');
        }
        this.lastscrolltop = scrollTop;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to loop through the headers inside the scroll event.

Comment: Hi! You mean the `el` or the `this.headers`? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the headers inside the scroll event as shown.  In other words, reverse your inner and outer loops.

Yet, a better way to do this is to wrap the headers in a container and toggle your class on the container. This way you avoid having to loop through the headers. Both methods are shown in the snippet.

Also note that you can replace your add/remove class logic with a single [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).  The optional second parameter is a Boolean which forces the class to toggle on or off.

**Snippet**

```js
let headers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-header]');
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let lastScrollTop = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', _ => {

  let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  // method 1 - toggle class on container
  container.classList.toggle('myclass', scrollTop > lastScrollTop);
  
  // method 2 - toggle class on all the headers
  // headers.forEach(el =>  el.classList.toggle('myclass', scrollTop > lastScrollTop));

  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;

});
```

```css
[data-header] {
  height: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

div.myclass header,             /* <--- for method 2 */
[data-header].myclass {         /* <--- for method 1 */
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<h4>Scroll down and up</h4>

<div id="container">

  <header data-header>
    my header
  </header>

  <header data-header>
    my second header
  </header>

</div>

<!-- spacer -->
<div style="height:100rem;"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, this is a clever one. Thank you!